# Are the default values for the different Django model fields documented somewhere?

Tags: django, django-models

In [this](http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial/part2.html#defaults) part of the south documentation it says

> "some columns don’t have a default defined".

**Which model fields get a default value when syncdb is used and which don't?** (The South documentation says for a `BooleanField` the default value is `False`)

I have searched accross the model /ref/ and /topic/ parts of the Django model related documentation but can't find this. Is this documented somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find the answer in the documentation either, so I checked the [source code for model fields](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py). The "default default" for every model field except `BinaryField` is provided by this method:

```
def get_default(self):
    """
    Returns the default value for this field.
    """
    if self.has_default():
        if callable(self.default):
            return self.default()
        return force_text(self.default, strings_only=True)
    if (not self.empty_strings_allowed or (self.null and
               not connection.features.interprets_empty_strings_as_nulls)):
        return None
    return ""
```

Consequently, the "default default" for most field types is determined by how `get_prep_value` handles an empty string. The various implementations of `get_prep_value` can be found in the [same source file](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py). It looks like most fields don't have a "default default", because most implementations of `get_prep_value` don't know what to do with an empty string. Notable exceptions to the rule are `BooleanField` (defaults to False), `CharField` (defaults to the empty string), and `TextField` (defaults to the empty string).

I hope this helps!